# Hiding a column in a table?

Tags: html, html-table

I'm making a table with:

- days as columns
- times as rows
- and the table data will be empty, styled anchors (changing between dots, lines and blocks).

When the display gets down to tablet/mobile size I want hide all but one of the days (columns).

As I understand it, as it is very obviously a table, I should probably use the table element. However hiding/styling tables/columns is problematic. I'd like to steer away from applying a column class to each td and I probably need to support ie8 so nth-child is out of the loop and col is too limited for the styling I need to do http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns.html.

So my question is; should I pursue the applying classes to td's or what is the most semantic alternative?

**Edit:**

I think I've decided to go with nested ul's. I'm sure semantically it's not correct but in terms maintainability I think using tables would nigh on impossible

Comment: from the ques. what i can depict is you want add different styling for tables & columns... should use css and apply into table and columns you wanted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you are unlucky. Just add a class to all the td's in a column. This is the best backwards compatible solution there is.

Here you can read all about '[ways to hide first column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866907/ways-to-hide-first-column-of-table-through-css)' on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That would work but it just feels a little clumsy having to add a class to every td - my time divisions are in 15 minute increments over 24 hours x 7 days, so I have 672 td's!

Comment: @Chris I understand that it would be nicer to do it differently, but if you want to support IE8 you don't have a lot of choice. Another thing. Did you test what happens if you open a table with 672 rows on a mobile device? I assume it will not perform that well. I personally would go for pagination loading data using AJAX.

Comment: it's 672 td's not tr's. Page size is currently 78kb so it'll be fine. I think I'm going to use nested ul's though, tables are too messy to style, especially when you get to mobile..